# Order of Points in ZoKrates proofs

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to verify a [ZoKrates proof](https://github.com/Zokrates/ZoKrates) with the [go-snark](https://github.com/arnaucube/go-snark) verification function (same bn128 parameters and G16 protocol). But for some reason it wont work and I suspect an issue in the order of the points.

In the [exported contract](https://github.com/Zokrates/ZoKrates/blob/master/zokrates_core/src/proof_system/bn128/utils/solidity.rs) the definition of the G1 point is a struct with two uints and the G2 is a struct with 2 [2]uints.

So the library declare the generators in this way:

```
    /// @return the generator of G1
    function P1() pure internal returns (G1Point memory) {
        return G1Point(1, 2);
    }
    /// @return the generator of G2
    function P2() pure internal returns (G2Point memory) {
        return G2Point(
            [11559732032986387107991004021392285783925812861821192530917403151452391805634,
             10857046999023057135944570762232829481370756359578518086990519993285655852781],
            [4082367875863433681332203403145435568316851327593401208105741076214120093531,
             8495653923123431417604973247489272438418190587263600148770280649306958101930]
        );
    }
```

Meanwhile the [go-snark package](https://github.com/arnaucube/go-snark/blob/master/bn128/bn128.go#L52) make it like this:

```
    b.Gg1 = [2]*big.Int{
        big.NewInt(int64(1)),
        big.NewInt(int64(2)),
    }

    g2_00, ok := new(big.Int).SetString("10857046999023057135944570762232829481370756359578518086990519993285655852781", 10)
    if !ok {
        return b, errors.New("err with g2_00")
    }
    g2_01, ok := new(big.Int).SetString("11559732032986387107991004021392285783925812861821192530917403151452391805634", 10)
    if !ok {
        return b, errors.New("err with g2_00")
    }
    g2_10, ok := new(big.Int).SetString("8495653923123431417604973247489272438418190587263600148770280649306958101930", 10)
    if !ok {
        return b, errors.New("err with g2_00")
    }
    g2_11, ok := new(big.Int).SetString("4082367875863433681332203403145435568316851327593401208105741076214120093531", 10)
    if !ok {
        return b, errors.New("err with g2_00")
    }

    b.Gg2 = [2][2]*big.Int{
        [2]*big.Int{
            g2_00,
            g2_01,
        },
        [2]*big.Int{
            g2_10,
            g2_11,
        },
    }
```

So the g1 points are in the same order (i guess) but the g2 points are reversed and I guess is the same with all the bn128 points (the ones in the pk,vk and proof). Is this because of a wrong declaration? or the array indexes in solidity are reversed? Are the struct declaration the same way?are the points in the proof.json and verification.key in a order to make them work in solidity?

I'm kind of lost on how I have to change the points order in the alpha, beta, gamma and delta   points in the proof and the verification key to make it work in a golang program. I'm not sure even of the input array order.

Answer (score 0):

So I figure it out. The short answer is that solidity and go have the same order of index as every sane language and the order doesn't  really matter iff the definition of the curve points are concordant.

My issue was that the definition of the G2 points are different in both package (the solidity contract and go-snark) So I changed to [clearmatic bn256](https://github.com/clearmatics/bn256) package for go that is especially constructed to work with ethereum and everything went fine.